# Is it possible to do a Group By in LINQ but then only return the 'most recent' item (per group)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to return the most recent item, per group, in .NET LINQ.

It reminds me of doing a `PARTITION` in Sql where we partition and get the top 1 per partition, ordered by most recent (per partition).

So far I've got the start of the linq code..

```
from p in products
group p by new {p.Provider.ProductId, p.Provider.Name} into g
```

But i'm not sure how to add the `order by p.CreatedOn desc` and just get the `.Take(1)`, *per partition/group*.

Comment: `select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First()` ?

Comment: or FirstOrDefault() would be better ?

Comment: no wai! omg ... /me runs off to try it...

Comment: @Alicia if there weren't any items, there wouldn't be a group in the first place, so the `OrDefault` would be redundant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like (appended at the end of your query):

```
select new {
    g.Key,
    Product = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First()
}
```

should do the job; or perhaps more conveniently:

```
select new {
    g.Key.ProductId,
    g.Key.Name,
    Product = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First()
}
```

Or if you don't need the key explicitly (because it is available under the item anyway), then just:

```
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).First()
```

Basically, each `g` is an `IGrouping<T>` (for some anonymous `T`), which means each `g` *has* a `.Key` property that is your group, and each `g` *is* an `IEnumerable<>` sequence of the original elements (presumably `Product`).